# Multiple submit buttons - binding of text field to submit button

Tags: html, forms

I have a simple HTML form with multiple submit buttons and I want my application to act differently on whichever submit button I click.

Example:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="test" name="test" />
    <input type="text" name="search_query" style="width: 300px; padding: 5px" value="some text">
    <input type="submit" value="Search" name="search" />
    <input type="text" name="search_query2" style="width: 300px; padding: 5px" value="some text">
    <input type="submit" value="Search" name="search2" />
    <input type="submit" value="GO" name="next" />
</form>
```

This works for me, and I know how to distinguish which button I clicked. The problem I have is that if I push <kbd>Enter</kbd> while editing the text-field then the first submit button gets clicked (the one named `test`). Is this possible to let the browser know (with HTML only - the whole point of this is to make it work with **NO** JavaScript) that I pushed <kbd>Enter</kbd> and it should send `search` with POST, not `test`?

So is there some kind of binding of text field to the submit button?

Comment: You could move the first submit, after the `search` submit?

Comment: yeah, but I can have for example 3 text inputs and a submit button for each of them.

Comment: Then there is no way to do it without duplication of entry OR javascript

Answer (score 0):

A solution to this problem would be to have multiple `form` elements, including your different `submit` buttons and the corresponding textfields.

I can't think of a solution with just one formular but no Javascript in use.

Comment: Won't work here because I have some other data which I need to send.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the one you want to be submitted to first in that list, like so:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="search_query" style="width: 300px; padding: 5px" value="some text">
    <input type="submit" value="Search" name="search" />
    <input type="submit" value="test" name="test" />
    <input type="submit" value="GO" name="next" />
</form>
```

But it seems that your HTML is just poorly formed, I'd recommend ***Merguez's*** answer

Since your edit, there is no way to do this without Javascript/jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

This would not be hard to do with PHP.
First: Change your  buttons to actual  controls:

becomes

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="search_query" style="width: 300px; padding: 5px" value="some 
text" />
<button type="submit" name="actionB" onclick="javascript:checkBtn();" value="Search">Search</button>
<button type="submit" name="actionB" onclick="javascript:checkBtn();" value="Test">Test</button>
<button type="submit" name="actionB" onclick="javascript:checkBtn();" value="Go">Go</button>
</form>
```

Now, when the form is submitted, check the returned value of actionB. If it's "Search", then piece together your search URL using the returned value of search_query.

There is NO way to read variables using only HTML. JavaScript is required if you're not going to use a scripting language to do this. You can totally do this in native JavaScript. JQuery is NOT required for this relatively simple function.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function checkBtn() {
 var btnX=document.getElementById("actionB").value;
if (btnX=="Search") {
 // compose your new URL here
}
// repeat for each of the possible buttons
</script>
```

Hope that helps somewhat!
Steve